# Edit grub file from recovery mode

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia

After a successful pass through of my GPU via `amd_iommu = on` and set to ignore the GPU id in the grub configuration I cant no longer access Ubuntu because it doesn't use my GPU any more.

I thought I had an integrated GPU but it seems like I haven`t configured it right.

Now my question is, can I edit grub from the grub Rescue mode?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can in Ubuntu at least. That is if you can start Grub in 'Recovery Mode'. After initialisation you can see a 'Options Menu'. Choose option 'Start Root Terminal' or something at the bottom. Now you are in the root shell where you can edit grub configuration files. Put the 'boot command line' back to normal or whatever you need and afterwards execute the 'update-grub' command... And done... I hope.
You can also edit tge 'boot command line' when you select the 'first menu option and than push the 'e'-key on your keyboard... Thre you can edut the 'BCL' to serve your needs... This is not a permanent option and it will be lost on the next bootup...